# How do I get the mercurial version in a django app?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to use the working directory's mercurial version info within a Django app. By version info, I really mean `<changeset, branch, and tag>`.

Are there plugins or techniques to do this?

I've got one way implemented in settings.py, but I haven't found a way I like to make these data available to code and templates. Any ideas?

I am aware of related techniques to write version info to a file or template, and that's not what I'm looking for.  Instead, I want version info in a variable within the Django app.

Environment: Ubuntu 11.04, virtualenv, Python 2.7, Django 1.3, Mercurial 1.9.x.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem? If you have e.g. `HG_REV` variable in `settings` module, you can access it from the rest of the code via `django.conf.settings` proxy, like any other setting. If you want to expose it to every template, then the easiest way is to write a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Comment: That looks like it will work.  I didn't realize that I could stuff custom settings into django.conf.settings.  Thanks!